# ¿que estoy haciendo mal al generar mi servidor https con ruby en kali?

Tags: webservice, ruby, http, rubygems, https

Resulta que estoy intentando montar un servidor web https y al intentarlo
me genera un error, el codigo es el siguiente:

con este codigo genere el certificado:

```
require 'webrick'
require 'webrick/https'

cert_name = [
%w[CN localhost],
]

server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 8000,
:SSLEnable => true,
:SSLCertName => cert_name)
```

luego de generarlo edite el archivo y puse esto:

```
require 'webrick'
require 'webrick/https'
require 'openssl'

cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new File.read '/path/to/cert.pem'
pkey = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new File.read '/path/to/pkey.pem'

server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 8000,
:SSLEnable => true,
:SSLCertificate => cert,
:SSLPrivateKey => pkey)
```

y me da este error:

```
./Servidorweb.rb:11:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /path/to/cert.pem (Errno::ENOENT)
from ./Servidorweb.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

alguno sabe a que se pueda deber? probe con el puerto 9000 y tambien me da error

Comment: ¿En qué directorio se encuentra el archivo `cert.pem`? Ese directorio es el que hay que incluir como ruta. Mira nuevamente [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/80675/42433), la actualicé para darte más de detalle.

Answer (score 0):

El error que obtienes es porque no se encuentra el archivo `cert.pem` en la ruta especificada (i.e. `/path/to/`). Probablemente la ruta que tienes actualmente en tu código (i.e. `/path/to/cert.pem`) sea únicamente un ejemplo, donde debes sustituir `/path/to` por la ubicación real de el archivo `cert.pem`.

Por ejemplo, si tu archivo estuviera un subdirectorio `certificados`, que a su vez está dentro del directorio `pruebas` el cual se encuentra en la raíz (i.e *raiz > pruebas > certificados*), la ruta sería `/pruebas/certificados/cert.pem`.

Para resolver el problema cambia la ruta por aquella donde se encuentren los archivos `cert.pem` y `pkey.pem`.

Considerando la ruta del ejemplo anterior (`/pruebas/certificados`), tu código se vería así:

```
cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new File.read '/pruebas/certificados/cert.pem'
pkey = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new File.read '/pruebas/certificados/pkey.pem'
```

---

#### Sobre rutas relativas y absolutas

Considera que al utilizar `/` al inicio estás utilizando una ruta absoluta, así que debes tener tu archivo en esa ruta.

Si deseas utilizar una ruta relativa, entonces quita el primer `/`; aunque considera que de esta forma deberás ejecutar el programa siempre desde el mismo directorio.

Por ejemplo, tu ruta relativa se vería así:

```
File.read 'path/to/cert.pem'
```

Entonces si ejecutaras tu programa desde `/home/app`:

```
home/app $ ruby Servidorweb.rb
```

Este buscaría el archivo en

```
home/app/path/to/cert.pem
```

Considerando lo anterior, siempre recomiendo utilizar rutas absolutas, tal como lo tienes en tu programa; solo verifica que esa ruta sea la correcta (en tu caso no lo es, por eso muestra el error).

Comment: Gracias @Mariano por el aviso! Desafortunadamente parece que la respuesta fue borrada antes que pudiera verla. Estaré pendiente en caso que modifiquen la pregunta original.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pri0K.png

Comment: @Mariano Excelente, gracias!